# Computer turns on when something else is turned on in the room

Tags: power-supply, sleep

I have a desktop PC plugged into a wall power socket that wakes up from sleep when some other device is turned on plugged into a power socket in the room (different socket other side of room, but most likely power running from the one wall socket to the other). Seems to depend somewhat on the load of the device turning on. e.g. plug a heater in and turn it on and the computer will wake from sleep.

Is their a bios setting or something else I can do to stop the computer waking from sleep in this fashion?

**UPDATE:**
Ok spent the last 30 min trying all sorts of different combinations to rule things out. Computer only wakes up when keyboard and mouse are plugged into the USB hub. Hub itself with nothing plugged in doesn't have an issue, only when keyboard + mouse plugged in.

So somehow fluctuations in power in the room result in the keyboard/mouse waking the keyboard up when going through the hub. Very odd. Anyone know why?

Comment: I wanted to see what your computer turned into.

Comment: A pumpkin? LOL. Fixed the typo.

Comment: Lol.  Also, unfortunately, I'd be highly surprised if you were able to configure this with bios settings.  A sure protector and/or other power managing device seems more likely.

Comment: The sleep mode in BIOS set to "S3 only". Have a USB hub (not powered) plugged in with keyboard and mouse plugged into that. DVI monitor, analog sound out for speakers and mic. Network cable. Wake on LAN is off.

Comment: Do you have it set in hibernate mode?  Would that be a workable configuration?

Comment: Well suspend to RAM much nicer/quicker. See my update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best guess would be that all the outlets are on the same circuit so a power drop on one outlet creates a power drop on all outlets.  Your computer is most likely plugged into a surge protector, not a UPS.  It is running in sleep mode so the processor is spun almost off, main power to all devices except for USB is mostly off.  Video, HDD... all spun down.  The USB power is kept for "Wake on USB".  Assumes USB keyboard and/or mouse.  Wake would bring system out of sleep when it detects keyboard input or mouse shake.

During the power blip, the USB 5 volt drops a bit since the power supply is mostly shut off.  Result is when the power comes back the USB sees almost like an input signal and wakes your computer.

Could try:  powered USB hub (maybe it won't be so sensitive to the power drop?) or UPS on computer.

Comment: Yes did forget to mention computer is plugged into a surge protector. That computer does not have a UPS. What does the surge protector have to do with anything? My understanding is it's only supposed to do something if you have a surge not drop/brown out. Or depending where/what you read basically nothing.

Comment: A UPS might hold up the system and not allow the hub power to drop.  The surge protector stops over voltage, but does nothing when the power dips - allows the sag to go through.

Answer (score 1):

You BIOS might be assuming there's power outage happened, as heater for example draws too much power, and most probably your "After Power Failure" option is set to **Always On** .

Try to find this option and set it to **Power Off** or **Last State** .

You might refer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/368891/desktop-bios-after-power-failure-setting-behavior) for more info

Comment: Good guess. But it's set to "Power Off". So not that. Don't think it's seeing it as a power outage, as turns on right away. i.e. data retained in RAM still there.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you should plug out the USB keyboard and mouse out of PC at the time sleeping, untill you want to get back, just press Power button to start the PC. Then plug in the mouse and keyboard again.
Another method is turn off the feature wake from mouse and keyboard by following this link:

> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/wake-from-sleep-only-with-power-button/566bafea-7e76-4e8e-a28e-e9844b91e205

Thanks you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).