# Windows 7 machine starts up automatically when connected to power source

Tags: windows-7, boot, hibernate

I recently got a Windows 7 laptop from my office. I am observing that it starts up (boot up/ wake up from hibernate) whenever it is connected to power source. This happens whether it is in shut down or is in hibernated state. There is no change of state when it is already powered on.

This does not happen in my personal laptop. Does anyone know of any option that is causing this? And how to disable this?

Comment: I would look into the powermanagement. Often there are vendor specific applications for this.

Comment: It happen for wrong BIOS settings. Add more information about laptop brand and model.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar thread on this site (Superuser) [over here](https://superuser.com/questions/368891/desktop-bios-after-power-failure-setting-behavior) It appears to be helpful in your case.

Regards,
dkp

Comment: This is likely the culprit