# Powered Laptop Automatically Starting Up (Unintended)

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, power

I recently had a hardware failure and replaced my hard drive with a new one. Then having done a fresh install of Windows 8.1 (which then was upgraded to Windows 10).

I'm having the same issue described here:
[Windows 7 machine starts up automatically when connected to power source](https://superuser.com/questions/755810/windows-7-machine-starts-up-automatically-when-connected-to-power-source)

The difference being this happening in Windows 10, and actually on my personal laptop. My BIOS does not show a tab for "Power" or options similar to it.

I'd appreciate help on diagnosing the problem, and then help on solving the issue.

**EDIT:**

Let me explain the various behaviors of my computer:

Battery always at (or close to) 100%

Scenario 1, computer plugged in at all times

1. Shutdown from Shutdown fired. Computer appears to power off.
2. Within 5 seconds, without any action, computer powers on stating, splash screen states "Resuming from Hibernate"

Scenario 2, computer unplugged in at all times

1. Shutdown from Shutdown fired. Computer appears to power off.
2. Stays shutdown.

Scenario 3, computer unplugged, then plugged in

1. Shutdown from Shutdown fired. Computer appears to power off.
2. Wait a few seconds, about 10 seconds. Computer does not turn on.
3. Plugin power source, computer instantly powers on and splash screen states "Resuming from Hibernate"

This is a Sager/Clevo Laptop.

Comment: Is it starting up at similar times? Have you checked Windows update?

Comment: @Burgi It start-up about 3 seconds after the computer has seemingly powered off. It is not on schedule.

Comment: How odd. Could you [edit] your answer with the make and model of your laptop please?

Comment: @Burgi Done. Also added the weird use cases to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is your machine model? Are there any related error or warning messages recorded in the Event Viewer(Windows Logs\System)?

Please ensure your device manufacturer website has released the Windows 10 compatible drivers for your model machine.

We could try to open an administrator command line and run "powercfg /lastwake" to check the trigger.
Run "powercfg -devicequery wake_armed" to list all the devices that are user-configurable to wake the computer from a sleep state.

Unplug all the external devices to have a troubleshoot.

Run "powercfg /energy" to get an energy report(you will get a energy report located in C:\Windows\System32 "depends on the command line location"). Pay attention to the warnings or errors.

Usually this issue could be related to a specific driver, we could try to boot into safe mode to have a troubleshoot.

Comment: I see one event, "Session "Circular Kernel Context Logger" stopped due to the following error: 0xC0000188". Based on [Windows Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2001347), this does not affect system behavior that it cannot handle an event to allow the system to start faster on next startup. The `powercfg` only shows my mouse and keyboard.